# Inherit from a WPF page

Tags: .net, wpf, inheritance

I have a page which contains an overridable property "FileName". 
I want to create the whole page and inherit from them to have same pages but with different filename.

Is this possible?

Main page XAML:

```
    <Page x:Class="Batcher_File"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:my="clr-namespace:TB_InstallSystem"
      DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600"
      Title="Batcher">
    </Page>
```

Codebehind:

```
Class Batcher_File
    Private _fiBatch As New IO.FileInfo(TB.SystemMain.AppPath & "myfile.xml")
    Public Overridable Property fiBatch As IO.FileInfo
        Get
            Return _fiBatch
        End Get
        Set(value As IO.FileInfo)
            _fiBatch = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Second Page XAML ??:

```
<!-- -->
```

Second Page Codebehind:

```
Public Class Batc_After
    Inherits Batcher_Filer

    Private _fiBatch As New IO.FileInfo(TB.SystemMain.AppPath & "batch_after.xml")
    Public Overrides Property fiBatch As IO.FileInfo
        Get
            Return _fiBatch
        End Get
        Set(value As IO.FileInfo)
            _fiBatch = value
        End Set
    End Property




End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing something very similar to this when I was building a wizard in WPF. The way I went about doing it was by creating a class (let's say "`MyPage`") that simply extends page and adds the `FileName` property to it. Then, when you want to use `MyPage`, declare it in the XAML as such. This way your XAML will look like more or less like:

```
<mynamespace:MyPage 
    xmlns:mynamespace="clr-namespace:PathOfNamespace"
    FileName="MyFileName.file">
    <some more XAML>
</mynamespace:MyPage>
```